# Highlight angular syntax in html template

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

Is there some addon for visual studio code, that will highlight angular syntax in html template?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XriFi.png)

now it's just look so like a mess.

Comment: I'd recommend you the one I've been developing lately: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ghaschel.vscode-angular-html

It's not perfect yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want proper syntax highlighting in your templates, the easiest way is to store your templates in their own files. This is what your example looks like in VSCode if you store that template in its' own `.html` file for example:

[image: Template Syntax Highlighting]

That said, if you want to keep using inline templates, [this plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=natewallace.angular2-inline) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this extension  [angular2-inline](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=natewallace.angular2-inline) I been used and It's very good

[image]